# Using closure for storing and retrieving data

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am trying to use closure for storing and retrieving variable at the same time.

I am using `JSONP` and callback to the function

`http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=geoIPInfo`

Closure

```
function geoIPInfo(newGeoData) {
    var geoInfo;
    if (newGeoData) {
        geoInfo = newGeoData;
    }
    var provideGeoData = function () {
        return geoInfo;
    };

    return provideGeoData();
}
```

I want firstly to store data and than retrieve last saved data from the closure using simple call like that

```
geoIPInfo()
```

If argument provided it will set new info otherwise it will return existing one.

But in my case data is set successfully, but when I try to get set data I get `undefined`

```
 $("#super_button").click(function (e) {
            alert(geoIPInfo());
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

What is wrong with my closure understanding ? 
Please explain.

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong is that each time you call geoIPInfo you create a new closure, you need the function to return the function object and not a function call and the use that function object as a regular function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work. The idea here is we create a function that returns a function with that accepts a parameter and we store geoInfo in a closure to keep it value. Idk if that makes sense, if you need a better explanation I can give it another try :)

```
var geoIPInfo  = function() {
    var geoInfo;
    var provideGeoData = function (newGeoData) {
        if (newGeoData) {
            geoInfo = newGeoData;
        }
        return geoInfo;
    };
    return provideGeoData;
}();
```

Comment: It works, thank you, could you explain what was the error as detailed as you can, thanks.

Comment: Here's a link to a book chapter that explains it way better than I could. https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md#nitty-gritty

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `geoIPInfo()`, you're re-declaring the local variable `geoInfo`. You'll want to declare `geoInfo` once, and have it accessible to `geoIPInfo()` via a closure:

```js
//Create a closure
var geoIPInfo = (function(){ 

  //Private variable, available via closure
  var geoInfo;

  function geoIPInfo(newGeoData) {
   
    if (newGeoData) {
      geoInfo = newGeoData;
    }
 
    var provideGeoData = function () {
      return geoInfo;
    };

    return provideGeoData();
  }

  return geoIPInfo;
})();

alert(geoIPInfo()); //undefined
geoIPInfo('Some Data');
alert(geoIPInfo()); //'Some Data'
```

Here, we're creating a closure using an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript).